# Trying to make a 4D6 drop lowet dice roller for DnD in Python, but can't remove chosen values from list or output to main() function

Tags: python, list, continue

I'm trying to shore up my coding skills so I thought it would be fun to make a character stat creator in DnD. I created a main() function that creates a dictionary of possible stats (STR, DEX, etc.), sets the initial value as 0, then passes the dictionary to different functions based on a user input (3d6, 4d6). At the moment, the program just runs through the dictionary and assigns values as they're rolled.

This is the code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# c_stats2.py

import random
import math

# 4d6 drop lowest
def m4d6(x):
    for stat in x:
        rolls = []
        for roll in range(4):
            r = random.randint(1,6)
            rolls.append(r)
        # Drop lowest number
        del rolls[rolls.index(min(rolls))]
        x[stat] += sum(rolls)
    return x

# 3d6 drop lowest
def m3d6(x):
    for stat in x:
        rolls = []
        for roll in range(3):
            r = random.randint(1,6)
            rolls.append(r)
        x[stat] += sum(rolls)
    return x

def main():
    method = input("Select stat method: ")

    stats = {'STR': 0,
            'DEX': 0,
            'CON': 0,
            'INT': 0,
            'WIS': 0,
            'CHA': 0
            }

    while True:
        if method == '4d6' or method == '4D6':
            stats = m4d6(stats)
            break
        elif method == '3d6' or method == '3D6':
            stats = m3d6(stats)
            break
        else:
            method = input('Please enter a valid method: ')
            continue

    for stat in stats:
        print(stat, ':' ,stats[stat], '\tBonus:' , math.floor((int(stats[stat]) - 10)/2))
    print("Initiative:", math.floor((int(stats['DEX']) - 10)/2))

main()
```

I wanted to add an option that would allow the user to actually choose where the stats were going. My thinking was that I would create a list of values rolled, assign them to a stat in the dictionary, then remove that value from the list of rolled values and return the dictionary to the new values. Here's the code so far.

```
# 4d6 drop lowest, choose stats
def m4d6c(x):
    val = [] 
    for dice in range(6):
        rolls = []
        for roll in range(4):
            r = random.randint(1,6)
            rolls.append(r)
        del rolls[rolls.index(min(rolls))]
        dice += sum(rolls)
        val.append(dice)
    for stat in x:
        print(val)
        print(str("Insert value for {}.").format(stat))
        dic = input('Value: ')
        if dic in val:
            x[stat] += dic
            val.remove(dic)
            continue
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid value")
            continue
    return x
```

The problem is the values aren't being assigned to the stats and aren't being removed from `val` list. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share your working on what you have done to debug/identify and resolve issues. there is no use of "continue" here. try to be more explanatory in describing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were close, but you forgot that `input` returns a string, and in `m4d6c` you need an `int` for your logic to work.

Current:

```
dic = input('Value: ')
```

Needed:

```
dic = int(input('Value: '))
```

Comment: That would explain it. I've added the int() component and it's working now. Thank you.